# Universal trying to display different nib files

Tags: ios, interface-builder

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0xa46e6a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

I've been researching this for the past couple of days but I haven't found an answer that gets my app to run.

I have a universal app with two nib files (one for phone, one for pad) and no matter what I change I keep running into this runtime error. I have triple-checked my connections in the Interface Builder. I also defined the main interfaces for both phone and pad respectively.

This is what my `AppDelegate.m` looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

ViewController *viewController;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
}else {
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
}

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[viewController release];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to check your xib files of ViewController.

1. Is the custom class of file's owner set to ViewController?
2. and view outlet connected to file's owner?

and then try it again.

Comment: Yes and yes. Unfortunately still running into the same error.

Comment: Thank u @Charles for your 2. Point. You are Rockstar.